# python scrapy different result when running from shell when as script

Tags: python, scrapy

[image]I have my script when I run script my print statement gives 'None' value. But when the same thing is run from scrapy shell I can get result what i want;
What can be reason for such different results;
Code is below

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess

class TestSpiderSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'test_spider'
    allowed_domains = ['dvlaregistrations.direct.gov.uk']
    start_urls = ['https://dvlaregistrations.dvla.gov.uk/search/results.html?search=CO11CTD"&"action=index"&"pricefrom=0"&"priceto="&"prefixmatches="&"currentmatches="&"limitprefix="&"limitcurrent="&"limitauction="&"searched=true"&"openoption="&"language=en"&"prefix2=Search"&"super="&"super_pricefrom="&"super_priceto='
]

    def parse(self, response):
        price=response.css('div.resultsstrip p::text').get()
        print(price)
        print('---+---')
        all_prices = response.css('div.resultsstrip p::text')
        for element in all_prices:
            yield print(element.css('::text').get())

[url][1]=''

process = CrawlerProcess()
process.crawl(TestSpiderSpider)
process.start()
```

this script when run gives None value, but when `response.css('div.resultsstrip p::text').get() '£250'` shell gives value what is located

Comment: Hi, to my research on finding the "resultsstrip" class in the div tag from the URL mentioned in start_urls, results is "did not find any class named as "resulsstrip". can you provide me the exact URL, or elaborate me what information you want to extract? I will help you because I also work on  scrapy and selenium.

Comment: sure! But have you tried also from scrapy shell, then it gives reslt of 250 pounds. `https://dvlaregistrations.dvla.gov.uk/search/results.html?search=CO11CTD&action=index&pricefrom=0&priceto=&prefixmatches=&currentmatches=&limitprefix=&limitcurrent=&limitauction=&searched=true&openoption=&language=en&prefix2=Search&super=&super_pricefrom=&super_priceto=`

Comment: Yeah the URL you provided above is the actual URL, replace the URL you are using in the code with the url mentioned above in the comment. and it will work file. Alexander gave the correct answer as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should edit your original post with the new url in your comment because the one in your question doesn't point to the same address.

Also you are trying to extract the text from a selector that points to the text only, that is why it is returning `None`.

In the following line your selector list already targets the `::text` of the element.

```
all_prices = response.css('div.resultsstrip p::text')
```

Which is why when you try to extract the `::text` again it doesn't work.

```
print(element.css('::text').get())
```

What would have worked would just calling `get` on the `element` itself.

```
print(element.get())
```

Try this:

```py
import scrapy
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess

class TestSpiderSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'test_spider'
    allowed_domains = ['dvlaregistrations.direct.gov.uk']
    start_urls = ["https://dvlaregistrations.dvla.gov.uk/search/results.html?search=CO11CTD&action=index&pricefrom=0&priceto=&prefixmatches=&currentmatches=&limitprefix=&limitcurrent=&limitauction=&searched=true&openoption=&language=en&prefix2=Search&super=&super_pricefrom=&super_priceto="]

    def parse(self, response):
        for row in response.css('div.resultsstrip'):
            plate = row.css('a::text').get()
            price = row.css('p::text').get()
            yield {"plate": plate.strip(), "price": price.strip()}


process = CrawlerProcess()
process.crawl(TestSpiderSpider)
process.start()
```

output:

```bash
&limitprefix=&limitcurrent=&limitauction=&searched=true&openoption=&language=en&prefix2=Search&super=&super_pricefrom=&super_priceto=>
{'plate': 'CO02 CTO', 'price': '£250'}
2023-01-14 15:22:25 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://dvlaregistrations.dvla.gov.uk/search/results.html?search=CO11CTD&action=index&pricefrom=0&priceto=&prefixmatches=&currentmatches=
&limitprefix=&limitcurrent=&limitauction=&searched=true&openoption=&language=en&prefix2=Search&super=&super_pricefrom=&super_priceto=>
{'plate': 'CO03 CTO', 'price': '£250'}
2023-01-14 15:22:25 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://dvlaregistrations.dvla.gov.uk/search/results.html?search=CO11CTD&action=index&pricefrom=0&priceto=&prefixmatches=&currentmatches=
&limitprefix=&limitcurrent=&limitauction=&searched=true&openoption=&language=en&prefix2=Search&super=&super_pricefrom=&super_priceto=>
{'plate': 'CO04 CTO', 'price': '£250'}
2023-01-14 15:22:25 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://dvlaregistrations.dvla.gov.uk/search/results.html?search=CO11CTD&action=index&pricefrom=0&priceto=&prefixmatches=&currentmatches=
&limitprefix=&limitcurrent=&limitauction=&searched=true&openoption=&language=en&prefix2=Search&super=&super_pricefrom=&super_priceto=>
{'plate': 'CO05 CTO', 'price': '£250'}
2023-01-14 15:22:25 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://dvlaregistrations.dvla.gov.uk/search/results.html?search=CO11CTD&action=index&pricefrom=0&priceto=&prefixmatches=&currentmatches=
&limitprefix=&limitcurrent=&limitauction=&searched=true&openoption=&language=en&prefix2=Search&super=&super_pricefrom=&super_priceto=>
{'plate': 'B14 CCD', 'price': '£399'}
2023-01-14 15:22:25 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://dvlaregistrations.dvla.gov.uk/search/results.html?search=CO11CTD&action=index&pricefrom=0&priceto=&prefixmatches=&currentmatches=
&limitprefix=&limitcurrent=&limitauction=&searched=true&openoption=&language=en&prefix2=Search&super=&super_pricefrom=&super_priceto=>
{'plate': 'B15 CCD', 'price': '£399'}
2023-01-14 15:22:25 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://dvlaregistrations.dvla.gov.uk/search/results.html?search=CO11CTD&action=index&pricefrom=0&priceto=&prefixmatches=&currentmatches=
&limitprefix=&limitcurrent=&limitauction=&searched=true&openoption=&language=en&prefix2=Search&super=&super_pricefrom=&super_priceto=>
{'plate': 'B17 CCD', 'price': '£399'}
2023-01-14 15:22:25 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://dvlaregistrations.dvla.gov.uk/search/results.html?search=CO11CTD&action=index&pricefrom=0&priceto=&prefixmatches=&currentmatches=
&limitprefix=&limitcurrent=&limitauction=&searched=true&openoption=&language=en&prefix2=Search&super=&super_pricefrom=&super_priceto=>
{'plate': 'B18 CCD', 'price': '£399'}
```